# Parsing evernote xml with element tree on python: how to find/delete elements with specific tag name

Tags: python, xml-parsing, tags, elementtree, evernote

I would want to get all text connected with en-todo elements from evernote note on xml. Is there any function to get all tags with specific name from root by one line?

I have tried root.findall("en-todo"), but it returns nothings.

Typical evernote note can contain en-todo elements with different levels of nesting. 
En-todo tags are often inside span tag, although sometimes the whole stack en-todo and text can be inside that span tag. It is making parsing quite complicated.
Is there any simple way to delete all span tags from xml with keeping its children? Can you suggest any other solutions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM
"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">
<en-note>
<div>
<en-todo></en-todo>
<span>one task</span>
</div>

<div><span><br clear="none"/></span></div>

<div><span>
<en-todo></en-todo>
<span>second task</span>
<br clear="none"/>
<span><en-todo></en-todo>third task</span>
<br clear="none"/>
<span><en-todo></en-todo>forth task</span>
<br clear="none"/>
<span><en-todo></en-todo>fifth task</span>
</span></div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it by xpath:

```
root.findall('.//en-todo')
```

This will find you all `en-todo` elements at any level of nesting.

Comment: Thanks, it's working! I would be glad if you also can give me a hint on span tag. It there any simple way to detect one tag followed by another? Like for the second task in my code above I would want to get the span tag text value taking into account this is kind of exceptional case for en-todo (e.g. for 3rd, 4th, 5th tasks I can just use element.tail).

Comment: @ivanovaos as far as I understand, you need to get the next following sibling of a node. I'm not sure if it's doable with elementtree easily. Are you ok to switch to [lxml](http://lxml.de)?

Comment: I will, as soon as the system will give me the opportunity, I need to collect 15 of reputation...Yes, you understand it correctly about the element. I can't switch, unfortunately. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @ivanovaos Try //en-todo/following-sibling::span[1]
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/293f6096fee51198e05af8c69aa1b7b0
It will get the first span following a en-todo tag.
I guess it's what you wanted (?)